# The condition on $\alpha$ that $\alpha^n$ is convergent modulo 1

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, sequences-and-series, diophantine-approximation

We consider numbers $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$ with $|\alpha|>1$. Is there any result about a characterization of those $\alpha$ so that $\{\alpha^n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent modulo 1?

I already found that characterizing those $\alpha$ such that $\{\alpha^n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is uniform distributed modulo 1, is a hard problem.

Motivation : Let $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Calculate the value $\lim_{n\to \infty} \cos(\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{5}}\varphi^{3n})$.

Since $\varphi^{3n}-\varphi^{-3n}=\sqrt{5}F_{3n}$ where $F_n$ is a $n$-th Fibonacci number, we can calculate the value $\lim_{n\to \infty} \cos(\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{5}}\varphi^{3n})$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number

Comment: @Puddlestheturtle: I think your comment pretty much answers the question. I recommend that you turn it into an answer!

Comment: @GHf, I don't think the Wikipedia page says anything about non-algebraic $\alpha$ (in the absence of square-summability). Then again, I don't think anything much is known, other than that uniform distribution holds outside a set of measure zero (we're tacitly assuming $|\alpha|>1$).

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it's not even known that $\{e^n\}$ doesn't converge to $0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: What I meant is: probably the Wikipedia page contains all that we know about this question (well, we can generate progress here, but it would be unusual for a well-studied question). For $|\alpha|\leq 1$ the problem is trivial of course.

Comment: @GHfromMO: I think your comment pretty much answers the question. I recommend that you turn it into an answer!

Comment: Maybe the reference to Mahler's 3/2 problem is also useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahler%27s_3/2_problem